# Imprimir uma variável de sessão através do motor twig

Tags: session, slim, twig

Introduzi uma variável na sessão designada `$_SESSION['ano']`. Gostaria de imprimir o seu valor numa página, utilizando o twig.

Já tentei:

```
{% for ano in app.session %}
    {{ ano }}
{% endfor %}
```

Mas não resulta. Como o posso fazer? O framework que estou a trabalhar é o Slim.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a resposta neste site:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643556/set-template-data-globally-in-slim-v3

No meu caso bastou acrescentar o seguinte:

```
$view->offsetSet("session", $_SESSION);
```

E no template: `{{session.nomedavariavel}}`.

Li noutros sitios que deveria ser: `$view->addGlobal("session", $_SESSION);`, mas não funcionou no meu caso.

**Actualização:** Afinal é possivel com o método `addGlobal`, inserindo:

> $view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal("session", $_SESSION);